# How to open url in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I open the url in a new tab? I know I must use _blank or window.open, but I cannot get it to work.

```
var url = 'https://google.com',
    delay = 5000; // Milliseconds: 1sec x 1000

   setTimeout(function () {
   window.location = url;
}, delay);
```

Comment: Note that a new tab (or window) will have to be opened while handling a user action, such as a link or button click. Browsers' popup blockers will prevent it in most other circumstances, including after a `delay`.

Comment: Yeah, I do have a button linked to the function. And even with it linked I still got a pop-up block that I had to enable.

Comment: Remove the `setTimeout()`. The window should be opened while the event is still being processed, and the timeout pushes it to after that.